# Do the OpenCV 2.3.1 Windows static libraries rely on zlib?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, static-libraries, zlib

I'm trying to get OpenCV 2.3.1 working inside a VS2010 setup. I was hoping to use the prebuilt static libraries because they seemed easiest. Basically all I'm doing is setting up the linker to link with all of the prebuilt libraries, but I'm still getting linker errors in the following test:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

int main()
{
  cv::Mat image;
}
```

I get linker errors to `_gzputs`, `_gzclose`, `_gzopen`, and a couple of others. They all seem to be related to the zlib library. The install instructions don't seem to say much about building zlib, and there's no prebuilt library (static .lib) that I can find for it. Does this mean that there's no way to use OpenCV 2.3.1 out of the box without compiling a 3rd party library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default openCV include support for loading png images. the libpng (which is used by openCV) require zlib. I suppose you can compile the openCV without support for png images and then you would not need the zlib.

Comment: Right -- I guess I'm confused because there's no pre-built .lib for libpng that I could find, so regardless you seem to have to build something. I've solved the problem by linking not with the static libs, but just the 'lib' folder, and then shoving all the required .dlls in the execution folder.

Comment: I never used OpenCV 2.3.1 but I also prefer to link statically so when I move to another computer to avoid installing all the other utilities